# What is the proper method to format and use derived classes inside of a Base* data structure?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, derived-class, base-class

### Intro

I am a little lost on the proper way to hold a data structure of multiple derived classes. I am relatively new to C++, so sorry if I have idiotic errors/misconceptions.

At the moment, I use a `vector<Base*>*`, which makes sense to me. However, I run into some issues when I try to use the objects contained in the vector.

## Issues I'm running into

I am going to use this sample set up to showcase my issues:

Base.h

```
class Base {

 public:
  Base();
  Base(int a, int b);
  virtual ~Base();

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Base& base);

  int getA();
  int getB();

 protected:
  int a;
  int b;

};
```

Derived.h

```
class Derived : public Base {

 public:
  Derived(int a, int b, int c);
  ~Derived();

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Derived& derived);

  getC();

 private:
  int c;

};
```

### #1: Using member functions of the derived classes

```
int main() {
  vector<Base*>* objects = new vector<Base*>();

  Base* newbase = new Base(0, 1);
  Derived newderived = new Derived(2, 3, 4);
  objects.push_back(newbase);
  objects.push_back(newderived);

  cout << objects->front()->getA() << endl; // '0'
  cout << objects->back()->getA() << endl; // '2'

  cout << objects->back()->getC() << endl; // error: 'class Base' has no member named 'getC()'
}
```

Despite the last object in `objects` being an instance of class `Derived`, it is recognized only as class `Base`. This of course makes perfect sense; `objects` hold `Base*`.

While I understand why the error is occurring, I'm confused on how to solve it. In my previous searches, I found that there were two commonly proposed (and also rather debated) solutions: including every member function my different derived classes use as a `virtual` function in `Base` and using static casting.

**What is the proper method/good practice for using member functions of derived classes inside of data structures containing `Base*`?**

### #2: Using friends: namely, overloading the insertion operator

```
int main() {

  vector<Base*>* objects = new vector<Base*>();

  Base* newbase = new Base(0, 1);
  Derived newderived = new Derived(2, 3, 4);
  objects.push_back(newbase);
  objects.push_back(newderived);

  cout << *(objects->front()) << endl; // Executed `Base`'s overloaded insertion operator
  cout << *(objects->back()) << endl; // Also executed `Base`'s overloaded insertion operator
}
```

In this case, I found very little reliable suggestions for solving this problem, other than "just use a print() method instead." I understand that I could work around this issue, but I would rather understand the proper way to implement something than just avoid using it.

**So, is it possible to somehow execute the derived class' overloaded insertion operator when called from a `vector<Base*>`? Any friend function?**

### #3: Identifying which derived class the object is

```
int main() {
  vector<Base*>* objects = new vector<Base*>();

  Derived newderived = new Derived(2, 3, 4);
  Derived2 newderived2 = new Derived2(5, 6, 7, 8);
  objects.push_back(newderived);
  objects.push_back(newderived2);

  if (/* objects->front() is a Derived */) cout << "Type check success << endl;
  if (/* objects->back() is a Derived2 */) cout << "Type check success << endl;
}
```

This problem, specifically, has been addressed several times before. The two solutions I have seen is somehow evaluating what occurs after a static cast and by storing some form of type list in the base class and storing a type value in all the derived classes.

However, as I mentioned before, I am new to C++, and I don't understand the former option or the proper way to implement the second. **What is the proper way to solve this problem, and are there any explained example videos or the like for me to investigate?**

I know this is a bit of a long question, but it seemed to me that it was all so closely interconnected that I should keep the three sub-questions together.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW There is almost never a need to create vectors dynamically. Just do `std::vector<Base*> objects;`

Comment: @Galik Thank you for the quick feedback; it was very helpful. In this case, I am required to use a dynamically allocated vector (I am a student, and this is for an assignment). I think the point is to cause mistakes with stacked dereferences and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO all of your problems stem from trying to fight against your chosen solution - *dynamic polymorphism*.

That technique works best when every *derived type* shares a **common interface**. The whole point of *dynamic polymorphism* is that the ***calling code*** does not need to know or care what the *actual* type is, it only cares that it uses a specific ***interface***.

In your example:

**1)** You are trying to use two *different* interfaces. Your dynamic
 polymorphism is acting through the `Base` interface and you want to use the `Derived` interface. With *dynamic polymorphism* pick your interface. If you need to know the specific type in a given part of the system then *polymorphism* is simply not the best solution in that area of the code.

**2)** The **proper** way to do that is to add a `print()` function. The idea is that every derived type knows how to print itself so that the calling code doesn't need to know or care how that is done.

**3)** In parts of the system where *dynamic polymorphism* fails (where you need to know the concrete type of the object) then the recommended way to discover the type is using a `dynamic_cast`:

```
if(auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(objects->front()))
{
     derived->getC(); // Derived specific calls
}
```

If the pointer is of the wrong type a `nullptr` is returned and the `if()` fails.

What I have found with `C++` is that *dynamic polymorphism* is really not the best solution for a lot of problems. There can be a temptation to try to make everything dynamically polymorphic but IMO that only works well for a given subset of object oriented design problems.

`C++` also excels in other areas such as *static polymorphism* (using the template engine) and *procedural polymorphism* (function overloading). These are well worth exploring too.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a non-abstract base class. In polymorphism, trying to seek if a method exists in the base/derived class is considered a wrong program practice. Declare the common methods instead as virtual.  Try this like so.

```
class Base {

public:
    Base();
    Base(int a, int b);
    virtual ~Base();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Base& base);

    virtual int getA();
    virtual int getB();
    virtual int getC() { return 0; }

protected:
    int a;
    int b;

};

class Derived : public Base {

public:
    Derived(int a, int b, int c);
    ~Derived();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Derived& derived);

    virtual int getA();
    virtual int getB();
    virtual int getC();

private:
    int c;

};

int main() {
    vector<Base*> objects;

    Base* newbase = new Base(0, 1);
    Derived newderived =  Derived(2, 3, 4);
    Base* pnewderived = &newderived;
    objects.push_back(newbase);
    objects.push_back(pnewderived);

    cout << objects.front()->getA() << endl; 
    cout << objects.back()->getA() << endl; 

    cout << objects.back()->getC() << endl; 
}
```